# Error while running cts-tradefed [for an android set top box]

Tags: cts, android-tradefederation

For google certification , we need to run **Compatibility test suite** on the android device(**stb**) .
I have done the setup for CTS on a Linux machine.
I am getting below error while running cts-tradefed on the machine.

```
./android-cts/tools/cts-tradefed
```

> Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx4g
>
> The specified size exceeds the maximum representable size.
>
> **Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.**
>
> **Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.**

*Can anyone give the solution for it?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just open `android-cts-[X.X]_[rX]-linux_x86-arm/android-cts/tools/cts-tradefed` from any text editor and change line number 131 `$RDBG_FLAG -Xmx4g` with any memory size which is less than your RAM size e.g. `Xmx3g`

Also check if you are using Linux 64Bit version. This issue might occur if you are using 32Bit(which is not supported)